# js masonry expanding box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

I cant find any solutions for this problem (see figure below).

[image: masonry with appended content]

What I'm trying to achieve is, after I clicked on the comment link, the masonry items should be able to adapt to the changes and reconfigure its display.

I've tried using

```
$container.masonry("reload");
```

basing on the example [masonry reload](http://desandro.github.io/masonry/docs/methods.html#reload) but so far not so good.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143859/jquery-callbacks-with-masonry-pluggin)

Answer:

```
$container.masonry();
```